# Many to Many Join Query in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, many-to-many

All previous attempts at a JOIN have left me with either the disc or item data populating the id, title keys of the result (maybe a clash is occuring).

So I have:

```
item table
fields: id, title

disc table
fields: id, title

item_disc table
fields: item_id, disc_id
```

How do I construct a double join so that I can access the related discs to an item. At present I am running two seperate queries, one for a single item record, then one for array of discs.

Apart from it being easier to do in one query with joins, if I ever want to retrieve more than 1 record, I would currently need to be running 2 queries per item as I cannot join my data.

Please help!! I feel this is my final many to many hurdle (though dare not speak too soon).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

because both item and disc have columns named id and title, they will overwrite each other. you would need to use `as` to distinguish them...

for all items and their associated discs:

```
select m.*, i.title as item_title, d.title as disc_title
from item i, disc d, item_disc m where i.id = m.item_id and
d.id = m.disc_id order by i.title, d.title
```

for one item and its discs:

```
select m.*, i.title as item_title, d.title as disc_title
from item i, disc d, item_disc m where i.id = m.item_id = ? and
d.id = m.disc_id order by d.title
```

replace ? with the item you want

Comment: apart from that being absolutely perfect!!!!! why do i not need to use JOIN (I am using ActiveRecord, and your query converted to that works as is). Confused now!

Comment: also, any clever way to make the result more intuitive to work with, i.e. item_id, item_title only once with subarray of discs? or do i just have to process it to my liking using a foreach.

Comment: @esrylx: basically sql isn't very good at "nested results", so it's up to the consumer of the data to loop over the result set and check when item_id changes to detect the end of the grouping...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a CodeIgniter implementation of many-to-many database relationships I'm compiling as a series of screencasts. This is abstract and is not intended to be used in a production environment as-is. As such, it should help to clarify the concept.

http://www.mattborja.com/web-development/codeigniter/databases/many-to-many-relationships-in-codeigniter-abstract/